# Redis "Error while reading line from the server." after Laravel 5.6 upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-horizon

After upgrading to Laravel 5.6 today, I'm encountering a lot of Redis errors all stating:

```
Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://redis.localhost:6379] {"exception":"[object] (Predis\\Connection\\ConnectionException(code: 0): Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://redis.localhost:6379] at /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:155)
```

The application stack includes:

- Laravel 5.6
- Horizon 1.0.6
- Echo 1.3.2
- Laravel Echo Server 1.3.6

Everything was running smooth on 5.5 and all the documentation I've found doesn't seem to address this case. There is no Redis usage through the facade or out of the service container within the application, besides some Cache usage.

Has anyone else been encountering this? I've triple checked the upgrade guide as well as the GitHub release notes and nothing there has struck out as being suspect. Based on the stack trace it appears to be Horizon related.

**Full Stack Trace**

```
#0 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(314): Predis\\Connection\\AbstractConnection->onConnectionError('Error while rea...')
#1 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(120): Predis\\Connection\\StreamConnection->read()
#2 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(112): Predis\\Connection\\AbstractConnection->readResponse(Object(Predis\\Command\\ListPopFirstBlocking))
#3 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(331): Predis\\Connection\\AbstractConnection->executeCommand(Object(Predis\\Command\\ListPopFirstBlocking))
#4 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(314): Predis\\Client->executeCommand(Object(Predis\\Command\\ListPopFirstBlocking))
#5 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php(96): Predis\\Client->__call('blpop', Array)
#6 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php(108): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connections\\Connection->command('blpop', Array)
#7 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/RedisQueue.php(230): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connections\\Connection->__call('blpop', Array)
#8 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/RedisQueue.php(213): Illuminate\\Queue\\RedisQueue->blockingPop('queues:events')
#9 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/RedisQueue.php(165): Illuminate\\Queue\\RedisQueue->retrieveNextJob('queues:events')
#10 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/RedisQueue.php(92): Illuminate\\Queue\\RedisQueue->pop('events')
#11 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(246): Laravel\\Horizon\\RedisQueue->pop('events')
#12 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(107): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->getNextJob(Object(Laravel\\Horizon\\RedisQueue), 'events')
#13 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('website_manager', 'events', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#14 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('website_manager', 'events')
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#16 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#18 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#19 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#20 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#21 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#22 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#23 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(865): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(241): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Laravel\\Horizon\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(143): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(88): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /var/www/manage.localhost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /var/www/manage.localhost/artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#29 {main}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this line in *config/database.php* file under **redis.default** key (or which ever connection name you have) solved it for me:

```
'read_write_timeout' => 0,
```